# Using long running Cron Jobs with Prestashop and Cloudflare CDN

Tags: cron, timeout, prestashop, cdn, cloudflare

So I've got Cloudflare and Prestashop running together to improve load times however a side effect of the CDN is that my cronjobs can only run for a maximum of 90 seconds. Any longer and Cloudflare will send out a 524 error and the cronjob will not be properly launched.

According to Cloudflare there are two ways to get around this problem. I can either reduce the size of the cronjob process so it fits within the 90 second window (which is not an option) or I can run the cronjobs on a separate subdomain that Cloudflare has no effect on. The problem with this option however is that Prestashop has something built into it so that regardless of what subdomain you use to visit the site it simply redirects to the main domain.

Does anyone have experience with this kind of issue and if so what are the best methods of getting around the problem. Thanks!

Comment: can you post the code of the file called by the cron?

Comment: I have several different ones. One that takes the customer database and imports emails to mailchimp, one that handles abandoned cart emails and one that checks on the progress of delivery via DHL and UPS and updates the order status in prestashop accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a fair bit of time I managed to resolve this issue. I had to modify a few of prestashop's controllers to add an exception for my particular subdomain.  I needed to amend an if statement on line 370 of shop.php (classes/shop/Shop.php) so that it looks like this (make sure you update "exemption.myshop.com" with your subdomain:

```
 if ((!$id_shop && defined('_PS_ADMIN_DIR_')) || Tools::isPHPCLI() || in_array($http_host, $all_media) || $http_host == 'exemption.myshop.com') {
```

I then had to modify two functions in frontController.php (classes/controllers/frontController.php). I needed to add the following piece of code to the top of both the sslRedirection and canonicalRedirection functions above everything else inside each of the functions.

```
        if (Tools::getHttpHost() == 'exemption.myshop.com'){
      return;
  }
```

Then I deleted class_index.php from the cache folder on the main directory and the changes were made. You can test to see if it has worked by visiting the subdomain, it should load the page without changing the url.

Answer (score 0):

All hosting have this issue in major or minor way. The problem is that a web server can't give an undefined process time to a single thread because it can consume all server resources in some point.

First thing is that you must be sure that your cron script has the ability of continue where it left last execution. You can do that saving periodically where the cron is processing and then when process stop and start again it can continue where it left. For example: if you are processing products you can save the last processed product ID (in your DB or a file), then when you execute your script again it can continue from the last processed product ID.

The second subject is that you must execute cron several times to be sure that process finish completely. You can make calculation knowing how much completely script take to finish execution. For example: 30 minutes in periods of 90 seconds, then you must execute your cron 20 time with 100 seconds of interval.

To execute cron you have some options:
- Hosting admin panel configuration.
- Operative system options.
- Prestashop free cronjob module.
- Third party service.

I hope this can help you.

Good luck.

Comment: That's an interesting concept and something I will definitely look in to but I'm not really sure how to go about doing that. The majority of the cron jobs I use are included with various prestashop modules so Ideally I'd want to find a solution that doesn't require me to modify the modules to get it working.

Comment: Hello. Use a third party services calculating frequency and delay for every cron you have. Or just use Prestashop cronjob module. Increase your hosting timeout if you can. Most of crons should not take long time to finish. If you can detect which specifically take long time it should be able to not star always from beginning after interruption. If not, you should modify it. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The domain redirection is not done in the admin context. Each Controller on FrontOffice will check the current URL and redirect to the canonical one if needed (if the domain is not the default one for example). But this mechanism doesn't exist on the BackOffice.

Then if you have for example a main domain `www.example.com` and a subdomain `cron.example.com`, if you try to access `cron.example.com/` you will be redirected to the default domain because you try to access the FrontOffice. But if you try to access the cronjobs module in backoffice it will work without redirection `http://cron.example.com/admin-1f5zef1/index.php?controller=AdminCronJobs&token=7498b7d228cc3e630ee2fe6b34bd1638`.

Tested and working on my website.

Comment: In that case how would I go about running my cronjobs through the admin area as they all have links that point to modules outside of the admin area?